# How to display fields in particular order in solr

Tags: solr

Whenever I want to display the records in solr I want the field to be displayed in the order specified by me.Like,

1. Title
2. Name
3. Desc
   But,the result is displaying in some random order like
   Name
   Desc
   Title

How to avoid this in solr6.

Comment: Could you add in your post an example of submitted query with its results?

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/acc_sea/select?fl=Address_Line_1,Address_Line_2,City,State,Zip,Country,Account_Name,Account_Code,Phone_Number,BIN_Number&indent=on&q="+searchParam+"&wt=json .............This is my query.....I want the field order as such given in the 'fl'.....But it is displaying in random order..

Answer (score 0):

Order it in your display layer or in your controller. Solr does not give any inherent order between the fields returned.